# Indeterminate behavior while using explicit wait

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have an array of several button id's like so:

```
string [] buttonIDs = {"buton1", ..., "button10"};
```

I am getting indeterminate behavior at the fifth button.  Each of these buttons uses the same clickButton function I have below:

```
 public static void ClickButton(string id)
    {
        try
        {               
            IWebElement button = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id(id)));
            button.Click();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception(" click button for timed out for " + id);
        }
    }
```

My error reads like so:

```
system.Exception: click button timed out for Button5
```

Sometimes it says:

```
system.Exception: click button timed out for Button6
```

I'm confused why my behavior would be indeterminate at all, and where to put the semaphore if that is the case.  Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: May be u can try using "driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait". This will specify the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for an element if it is not immediately present.

Comment: What is different about the 5/6th buttons? Are they hidden or ? Can yoiu share the page or post the HTML of a button that works and one that doesn't?

Comment: On your catch, you should catch only a specific exception otherwise you could be getting some unexpected exception and logging that it was a time out which will make debugging much harder.